# Android permissions protection levels 18 and 50

Tags: java, android

When I do a dump of all permissions on all apps on a Nexus 7 I get (as expected) permissions with protection levels 0 (NORMAL), 1 (DANGEROUS), 2 (SIGNATURE). Nothing is logging under 3 (SIGNATURE_OR_SYSTEM)*.

But there are also a lot of permissions whose protection level is set at '18' and some that are '50'.

I can't find any documentation on what these values represent. Does anybody know?

*It's not logging anything under 3.

These are what was logged:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM - 18
android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES - 18
android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER - 18
android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER_ADVANCED - 18
android.permission.ACCESS_MTP - 18
android.permission.ALLOW_ANY_CODEC_FOR_PLAYBACK - 18
android.permission.BACKUP - 18
android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET - 18
android.permission.BIND_DIRECTORY_SEARCH - 18
android.permission.BIND_KEYGUARD_APPWIDGET - 18
android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS - 18
android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER - 18
android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED - 18
android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE - 18
android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION - 18
android.permission.CONNECTIVITY_INTERNAL - 18
android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES - 18
android.permission.CRYPT_KEEPER - 18
android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES - 18
android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES - 18
android.permission.DOWNLOAD_CACHE_NON_PURGEABLE - 18
android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH - 18
android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER - 18
android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES - 18
android.permission.MANAGE_USB - 18
android.permission.MANAGE_USERS - 18
android.permission.MASTER_CLEAR - 18
android.permission.MODIFY_APPWIDGET_BIND_PERMISSIONS - 18
android.permission.MODIFY_NETWORK_ACCOUNTING - 18
android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE - 18
android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS - 18
android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS - 18
android.permission.MOVE_PACKAGE - 18
android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS - 18
android.permission.PACKAGE_VERIFICATION_AGENT - 18
android.permission.PERFORM_CDMA_PROVISIONING - 18
android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER - 18
android.permission.READ_NETWORK_USAGE_HISTORY - 18
android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE - 18
android.permission.REBOOT - 18
android.permission.RECEIVE_DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE - 18
android.permission.RECEIVE_EMERGENCY_BROADCAST - 18
android.permission.RETRIEVE_WINDOW_CONTENT - 18
android.permission.SEND_SMS_NO_CONFIRMATION - 18
android.permission.SERIAL_PORT - 18
android.permission.SET_TIME - 18
android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT - 18
android.permission.SHUTDOWN - 18
android.permission.STATUS_BAR - 18
android.permission.STOP_APP_SWITCHES - 18
android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS - 18
android.permission.UPDATE_LOCK - 18
android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS - 18
android.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES - 18
android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE - 18
com.android.chrome.TOS_ACKED - 18
com.android.launcher.permission.PRELOAD_WORKSPACE - 18
com.android.vending.TOS_ACKED - 18
com.android.vending.billing.ADD_CREDIT_CARD - 18
com.android.vending.billing.BILLING_ACCOUNT_SERVICE - 18
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND - 18
com.google.android.gallery3d.permission.GALLERY_PROVIDER - 18
com.google.android.gtalkservice.permission.SEND_HEARTBEAT - 18
com.google.android.partnersetup.permission.UPDATE_CLIENT_ID - 18
com.google.android.permission.BROADCAST_DATA_MESSAGE - 18
com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES - 18
com.google.android.xmpp.permission.BROADCAST - 18
com.google.android.xmpp.permission.XMPP_ENDPOINT_BROADCAST - 18

android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION - 50
android.permission.DUMP - 50
android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS - 50
android.permission.READ_LOGS - 50
android.permission.SET_ALWAYS_FINISH - 50
android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE - 50
android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP - 50
android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT - 50
android.permission.SIGNAL_PERSISTENT_PROCESSES - 50
android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS - 50
```

Comment: What are the permission names and values for the 18 and 50 levels? Are any of the apps ones from the AOSP, that you can examine the source for?

Comment: How do you dump it? Many of the 18 are just `signatureOrSystem` and 50 are just `dangerous`.

Comment: Dumping it via Logcat (iterating across all ApplicationInfo's/PackInfo's and forming a set of all Permissions) The value is taken from PermissionInfo.protectionLevel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just saw an old unanswered question. Although you might already get your answer, I'll answer it anyway. It may help others. :)

> there are also a lot of permissions whose protection level is set at '18' and some that are '50'.

The following code is retrieved from PermissionInfo.java in Android Source:

```
/**
 * Additional flag for {@link #protectionLevel}, corresponding
 * to the <code>system</code> value of
 * {@link android.R.attr#protectionLevel}.
 */
public static final int PROTECTION_FLAG_SYSTEM = 0x10;

/**
 * Additional flag for {@link #protectionLevel}, corresponding
 * to the <code>development</code> value of
 * {@link android.R.attr#protectionLevel}.
 */
public static final int PROTECTION_FLAG_DEVELOPMENT = 0x20;
```

So if there is a signature/system permission, the level would be 18(0x10 | 0x2). If the permission use used for special development tools, it would be 50(0x10 | 0x20 | 0x2).

> I can't find any documentation on what these values represent. Does anybody know?

As I [answered in an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14887969/1365960), you can checked the protection level and the description of these permissions in `frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml` and `frameworks/base/data/etc/platform.xml`. I post some of them here for your reference.

```
<!-- Configure an application for debugging. -->
<permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.DEVELOPMENT_TOOLS"
    android:protectionLevel="signature|system|development"
    android:label="@string/permlab_setDebugApp"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_setDebugApp" />

<!-- @hide Package verifier needs to have this permission before the PackageManager will
     trust it to verify packages.
-->
<permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_VERIFICATION_AGENT"
    android:label="@string/permlab_packageVerificationAgent"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_packageVerificationAgent"
    android:protectionLevel="signature|system" />
```

If there is a `@hide` annotation on that xml block, you cannot find any resources from documentation about this permission.

Answer (score 2):

The development permission 0x20 that composes the ones you are referring to are a set of permissions introduced by Google to be used during Android development and they are never granted by the `PackageManager` automatically. To be able to use them you must grant using `adb shell pm grant permission` .

You can see the code that does that and the change that was introduced by Google on this [02/21/2012 commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/e639da7baa23121e35aa06d6e182558e0e755696%5E!/).

Comment: when you say permission do you mean something like android.permission.MAIN_APP_DISPLAYED?