# Questions about Android Permissions

Tags: java, android, android-source

I was looking at the classes related to permissions on Android and I have a couple of questions.

In  [BasePermission](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/BasePermission.java) class, I see three fields defined: TYPE_NORMAL, TYPE_BUILTIN and TYPE_DYNAMIC. What do these represent? I'm guessing TYPE_DYNAMIC is for when addPermission() API method is used dynamically by the app to create a permission, but I'm not at all sure about the other two.
Does Android keep track of how permissions were created (i.e., defined by the system, a system app or a third-party app)? It seems that PermissionInfo class keeps track of some flags, but I couldn't find any flag that directly corresponded to how the permission was created.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Faraz is right but i have some additions. I was exploring the android source code and i found some information.

> 1. You can only add, update or remove TYPE_DYNAMIC permissions.
> 2. TYPE_DYNAMIC permissions are defined by application developers.
> 3. TYPE_BUILTIN permissions can only be acquired by system apps.

EDIT: TYPE_DYNAMIC permission example [How to use custom permissions in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816623/how-to-use-custom-permissions-in-android)

Comment: What's the source of this information? I don't think it's correct. I was printing the values for the permissions and Internet permission also seems to be TYPE_BUILTIN.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the TYPE_BUILTIN is for Linux kernel permissions, TYPE_DYNAMIC is for any dynamically created permission (via the use of addPermission*() API methods) and TYPE_NORMAL is for any other statically created permission (both system and third-party).

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887948/android-create-new-system-permission-in-through-aosp-source-code) explains where in the system code these permissions are defined.